# Auto-incrementing macro expansion

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

With using plain **C** preprocessor macros, is it possible to create something like:

```
INIT_BASE(0x100)                     // init starting number

#define BASE_A  GET_NEXT_BASE         // equivalent to #define BASE_A 0x101
#define BASE_B  GET_NEXT_BASE         // 0x102
#define BASE_C  GET_NEXT_BASE         // 0x103
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a preprocessor #define ? Why not just an enum ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros can't do that type of counting automatically, but `enum`s can.

```
#define INIT_BASE 0x100
enum foo
{
    BASE_A = INIT_BASE + 1,
    BASE_B,
    BASE_C,
    ...
};
```

Unless you *really* want to use macros, you are going to have to do the counting manually:

```
#define INIT_BASE  0x100
#define BASE_A    (INIT_BASE + 1)    // equivalent to #define BASE_A 0x101
#define BASE_B    (INIT_BASE + 2)    // 0x102
#define BASE_C    (INIT_BASE + 3)    // 0x103
```

Comment: ...and you want to put parentheses around the `INIT_BASE + N` expression.

Comment: beautiful!! i was under false assumption that enum's take up memory at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
#define BASE_A  (INIT_BASE+1) // equivalent to #define BASE_A 0x101
#define BASE_B  (BASE_A+1)         // 0x102
#define BASE_C  (BASE_B+1)         // 0x103
```

?