# C++ Macro expanding in ordinal numbers

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a code that compiles on various platforms having different features on or off (each represented by a specific define) and I am scratching my head on how to do the following switch (int) statement that would keep "case (number):" ordered and continuous.

```
int funcParam;
switch(funcParam)
{
case 0: break;

case 1:break;

#ifdef FEATURE_1
case 2: break;
#endif // FEATURE_1

case 3: break;  // <<== problem here: 3 follows 1 if FEATURE_1 is not defined

#ifdef FEATURE_2
case 4: break; <<== problem here: 4 follows 2 if FEATURE_1 is not defined
#endif // FEATURE_2

#ifdef FEATURE_3
case 5: break; <<== problem here: 5 follows 2 or 3 or 4 depending on features
#endif // FEATURE_3
}
```

Each case block of code is a block of 10 or so lines, I guess this is irrelevant, however the perfect solution to have would be to find a way to emit code like:

```
case NEXTNUM:
```

that would expand to a next ordinal number with each expansion of a macro NEXTNUM.
Not having an idea on how could it possibly be written.

Please keep in mind that I am using quite old compiler (C++98, may consider C++03).

EDIT:

Found eventually a very similar question here:
[Auto-incrementing macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979405/auto-incrementing-macro-expansion)
which boils down to a very simple solution that is using enums instead of just plain numbers.

Thanks, Radek

Comment: don't just *consider*. Do. C++98 is really not an option.

Comment: When everything is a hammer, everything else looks like a nail. The same goals can be accomplished using different approaches, without involving a `switch` statement. Did you try thinking outside the box, and consider different ways to structure the code that has the same logical results?

Comment: Why do you care about the order in which cases are written in the code?

Comment: A “block of 10 or so lines” following a `case` statement should almost certainly be a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create variables equal 0 and 1 depending on if the feature is enabled. Add these variables to cases after the feature case.

```
int main() {
    int funcParam;
    const int add_feature_1 = 
#ifdef FEATURE_1
        1
#else
        0
#endif
        ;
    const int add_feature_2 = 
#ifdef FEATURE_2
        1
#else
        0
#endif
        ;
    const int add_feature_3 = 
#ifdef FEATURE_3
        1
#else
        0
#endif
        ;
    switch(funcParam) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: break;
#ifdef FEATURE_1
    case 2: break;
#endif
    case 2 + add_feature_1: break;
#ifdef FEATURE_2
    case 3 + add_feature_1: break;
#endif // FEATURE_2
#ifdef FEATURE_3
    case 3 + add_feature_1 + add_feature_2: break;
#endif // FEATURE_3
    }
}
```

Consider refactoring your code, so that FEATURE_X has to be defined (which I consider better) and instead define FEATURE_X to number 0 or 1. Then you could:

```
#define FEATURE_1 0
#define FEATURE_2 1
#define FEATURE_3 0
int main() {
    int funcParam;
    switch(funcParam) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: break;
#if FEATURE_1
    case 2: break;
#endif
    case 2 + FEATURE_1: break;
#if FEATURE_2
    case 3 + FEATURE_1: break;
#endif // FEATURE_2
#if FEATURE_3
    case 3 + FEATURE_1 + FEATURE_2: break;
#endif // FEATURE_3
    }
}
```

Or similar combinations, you should get the idea.

Comment: I found a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979405/auto-incrementing-macro-expansion which is exactly what Marcus replied below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

instead of `case 0`, `case 1`… and so on, use values from an `enum`; these are also compile-time constants, and thus, legal as `case` values.

You can insert the same `#ifdef` feature checks into the `enum` definition, then the enum options are still continuously labeled.

Rule of thumb though:

1. you're not making anything prettier that way. Honestly, having a feature enabled or not should probably not change the values functions exchange – that's just ugly and a recipe for debugging disaster. So, I question your motivation!
2. a `case` costs nearly nothing. Instead or removing these cases, you should probably think about what the right operation is when that case is triggered. A warning? A system shutdown?
3. The fact that you're not using an `enum` in `switch`/`case` is a really um, bad sign, and you relying on cases still being contiguously numbered is actively worrying. Using magic numerical constants is bad enough style on its own – making them have different meanings on different feature sets screams "architectural mistakes have been made". I'd duly replace all my magic numeric values with entries from an enum. You *will* be happier afterwards.

Lastly: uff. C++98. C++03 is 20 years old. It's an important bug-fix release that basically broke nothing. You really should not hesitate a second to use it.